# How can I use a Jinja2 template inside a Python program?

Tags: python, html, templates, html-email

I have one python script which I want to execute as a daily cron job to send emails to all users. Currently I have hard-coded the html inside the script and it looks dirty. I have read [the docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), but I haven't figured out how can I render the template within my script.

Is there any way that I can have the separate html file with placeholders which I can use python to populate and then send as the email's body?

I want something like this:

```
mydict = {}
template = '/templates/email.j2'
fillTemplate(mydict)
html = getHtml(filledTemplate)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to expand on @Mauro's answer. You would move all of the email HTML and/or text into a template file(s). Then use the Jinja API to read the template in from the file; finally, you would render the template by providing the variables that are in the template.

```
# copied directly from the docs
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates'))
template = env.get_template('mytemplate.html')
print template.render(the='variables', go='here')
```

This is a [link](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#basics) to an example of using the API with the template.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking to do the same thing using Jinja within the Flask framework. Here's an example borrowed from [Miguel Grinberg's Flask tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xi-email-support):

```
from flask import render_template
from flask.ext.mail import Message
from app import mail

subject = 'Test Email'
sender = 'alice@example.com'
recipients = ['bob@example.com']

msg = Message(subject, sender=sender, recipients=recipients)
msg.body = render_template('emails/test.txt', name='Bob') 
msg.html = render_template('emails/test.html', name='Bob') 
mail.send(msg)
```

It assumes something like the following templates:

**templates/emails/test.txt**

```
Hi {{ name }},
This is just a test.
```

**templates/emails/test.html**

```
<p>Hi {{ name }},</p>
<p>This is just a test.</p>
```

Comment: Also `flask.render_template_string` if you want to pass a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/), a template language for Python. It has template inheritance feature. Look at this [example](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/intro/#basic-api-usage) from official docs.

Comment: but how can i get that inside python program , i mean load template inside python , fill it and then get the html of that

Comment: Fixed references, tks!